# Apply CSS to Sharepoint Site on one individual Web part

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This is being done in sharepoint 2013. I want to apply `height:0px` to a certain web part. I have its DIV ID as `MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl41_g_3d56d9c5_7b24_4bb9_9b84_ac3459578026_cell`

I tried putting the code in my style sheet (which is loaded, other stuff from the style sheet works)

```
MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl41_g_3d56d9c5_7b24_4bb9_9b84_ac3459578026_cell{height:0px;}
```

but that doesn't seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the pound:

```
#MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_ctl41_g_3d56d9c5_7b24_4bb9_9b84_ac3459578026_cell {
   height:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so stupid for not realizing this. 
EDIT, for others trying to do the same thing. I also had to add !important to override the default sharepoint value. But it works. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a css class to identify the Web Part (and to avoid using the ugly client id that asp.net provides to the .net controls). In order to do that i use the **CssClass** property assigning a css class name used later to apply the desired functionality.

like:

```
<wpPrefix:myWebPart id="someID" CssClass="myCustomCssClass" runat="server" />
```

and the css class defined wherever i need:

```
.myCustomCssClass{
    height: 0px;
}
```

i hope it helps!